# Splitting a string received from Json response

Tags: java, json, string

I am stuck in this for a very long time.Any help would be appreciated.
In my app,I am using android volley to get a json response. 
I am getting a response from a url with a key-value pair like this:

```
description: "This Collection channels a contemporary flavour to the flowy top. The cape-styled sleeves add a heroine spin to the everyday ensemble and all you need to do is to team this with your favourite basic for a polished look. - Polyblend - Round neckline - Long sleeves - Slip-on style - Regular fit - Unlined Colour: Navy Care label: Hand wash only at maximum temperature of 40 degree celcius Composition: 95% Polyester, 5% Spandex Model's body measurements: Height: 175cm Bust: 32"/80cm Waist: 23"/59cm Hips: 35"/89cm Size of model's garment: S Measurements: Shoulder Length x Sleeve Opening x Bust circumference x Waist circumference x Hem circumference x Length - XS (36.5cm x 26.5cm x 83cm x 87cm x 99cm x 58.5cm) - S (37cm x 26cm x 87cm x 92cm x 103cm x 58.5cm) Production country: ",
```

I want to split this string and display it as follows:

This collection channels a contemporary flavour to the flowy top. The cape-styled sleeves add a heroine spin to the everyday ensemble and all you need to do is to team this with your favourite basic for a polished look.

- Polyblend
- Round neckline
- Long sleeves
- Slip-on style
- Regular fit
- Unlined

  Colour: Navy

  Care label: Hand wash only at maximum temperature of 40 degree celcius

  Composition: 95% Polyester, 5% Spandex

  Measurements: Shoulder Length x Sleeve Opening x Bust circumference x Waist circumference x Hem circumference x Length
- XS (36.5cm x 26.5cm x 83cm x 87cm x 99cm x 58.5cm)
- S (37cm x 26cm x 87cm x 92cm x 103cm x 58.5cm)

Comment: How do you know where the line breaks are? According to the data you posted, there aren't any indications. It's easy enough to split on `-` to create your bullets, though.

Comment: @MattJacob There are no line breaks. The data is the same as posted. But it i want to display it in the given way. Is it possible?

Comment: Would you happen to have any control over the server? Can you change the data's format?

Comment: Well, you could insert two line breaks immediately before you find something matching the pattern `key: value`, but that breaks down if there's a colon anywhere else in your content.

Comment: He'd also have to account for the hyphens to get the bullet points.

Comment: @Hassan no I dont have any control over the server

Comment: I don't think you can ever get it to be perfect tbh. But you can try putting new line characters before the " - " and also before the "key: value" pattern like Matt said. This won't work for "Care label: ..." in your example, but maybe if that's going to be a common key, you can hard code it into your program.

Comment: Or maybe only consider a key if it starts with a capital letter, since they all seem to here. Of course, this is only one example though, so I don't know if that will change for other descriptions.

Comment: @Hassan each description is similar to the example given. I think i can consider a key to start with a capital letter. I'll try this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding new lines before each string `" - "`, as well as the `"key: value"` pattern.

In the example, all keys in the `"key: value"` pattern started with a capital letter, so only consider a key if it starts with a capital.

While this would work for this example, a description containing `" - "` or `": "` would add unnecessary new line characters or bullets. I believe an imperfect solution like this will have to suffice with the provided data.